# How to create APK using trigger.io

Tags: android, apk, trigger.io

I am developing an android application using a free/trial trigger.io account.
is it possible to create the apk without having a google dev account??

Thanks!

Comment: Unlike the situation with iOS, on Android a Google developer account is not required to create, test or distribute an APK, but only if you wish to distribute through the Google Play store. So it wouldn't be an "Android" restriction there.  That doesn't mean that whoever runs trigger.io may not have some requirements or limitations on their trial service - but it doesn't seem immediately obvious why such a limitation would be linked to not having an account with Google.

Comment: It seems that trigger.io platform adds this [restriction](https://trigger.io/docs/current/recipes/release/release_mobile.html)

Comment: @What makes you say that?  I don't immediately see any such indication at your link.

Comment: On 'Creating an APK' topic, it says "all required"